# How to get a reference to the event's source element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside an event listener, I need a reference to the element that was the event source. How do I get that?

This should be a no-brainer for anyone doing JavaScript for some time.

All the functions including the event handler are in global scope, and therefore, implicitly made a part of the DOM `window` object.

```
function WireHandlers() {
    $('.updateResourceImageButton').click(UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler);
}

function UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler() {
  // I would like a reference to the hyperlink/anchor
  // that was actually clicked, i.e. the hyperlink that
  // was the source of this event

  // would the keyword 'this' evaluate to the element I need?
  // or will it evaluate to the HTML DOM 'window' object
  // in this context?
}

$(document).ready(function () { WireHandlers(); });
```

Comment: _"would the keyword 'this' evaluate to the element I need?"_ Why don't you test it? Yes, `this` refers to the clicked element.

Comment: Did you see what `console.log(this)` was?

Comment: @undefined I would have, except that at times, it's more convenient to ask, esp. if you are a bit uncomfortable with the tools/support that forms the language ecosystem. It would have taken me more time than I have spent in receiving an answer from you guys if I had tried it myself, and that would have interrupted my train of thought. As a programmer, you know how expensive that can be.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. Sometimes, unless you've been programming the language day in day out for a very long time, you miss the most obvious things. So, I didn't even though I usually do. Plus, my code was in a state that it didn't, well, compile (you know what I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this

```
$(this)
```

also this is from jquery documentation

```
var target = $( event.target );
```

as in this page http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ and look at this article for more information  http://www.pkshiu.com/loft/archive/2009/01/understanding-this-this-and-event-in-a-jquery-callback-function

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 : you are welcome, if this answer was what you needed you can mark it as true answer

Comment: Sure. There is a time limit I have to wait before I can mark an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the function by reference you still get access to the parameters as normal. As such `event.target` or `this` will be the clicked element within the `UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler` function:

```
function UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler(e) {
    // clicked element as a native DOM element
    var foo = e.target; 
    var bar = this;

    // jQuery object containing clicked element
    var $foo = $(this);
}
```

Note, both `foo` and `bar` in this example will contain the same value.